# Getting all elements on the page with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, puppeteer

I wrote a web page crawler that successfully crawls a web page and grabs the data of one job posting using `puppeteer`. I'm now trying to get all the elements on the page with the class of `.opportunity` and then pass it into a function that will get the data for that specific job posting. However the list of `getElementsByClassName` is returning an empty object?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

async function crawlOpo(opo) {

    const opportunity = {
        title: '',
        desc: '',
        category: '',
        reqName: '',
        hours: '',
        postingDate: '',
        locationName: '',
        address: ''
    };

    const title = await page.evaluate(() => {
        try {
            return opo.querySelector('.row .col-lg-20 h3 a').innerText
        } catch(err) {
            return err
        }
    });
    const desc = await page.evaluate(() => {
        try {
            return opo.querySelector('.hidden-xs.paragraph').innerText
        } catch(err) {
            return err
        }
    });

    const category = await page.evaluate(() => {
        try {
            return opo.querySelector('.row.paragraph .col-sm-18 .row .col-md-8 .label-with-icon span').innerText
        } catch(err) {
            return err
        }
    });

    const reqName = await page.evaluate(() => {
        try {
            return opo.querySelector('.row.paragraph .col-sm-18 .row .col-md-8:nth-of-type(2) .label-with-icon span').innerText
        } catch(err) {
            return err
        }
    });

    const hours = await page.evaluate(() => {
        try {
            return opo.querySelector('.row.paragraph .col-sm-18 .row .col-md-8:nth-of-type(3) .label-with-icon span').innerText
        } catch(err) {
            return err
        }
    });

    const postingDate = await page.evaluate(() => {
        try {
            return opo.querySelector('.row .col-lg-4 h3 small').innerText
        } catch(err) {
            return err
        }
    });

    const locationName = await page.evaluate(() => {
        try {
            return opo.querySelector('.row.paragraph:nth-of-type(2) .col-lg-20 div div candidate-physical-location address span:nth-of-type(2) span').innerText
        } catch(err) {
            return err
        }
    });

    opportunity.title = title;
    opportunity.desc = desc;
    opportunity.category = category;
    opportunity.reqName = reqName;
    opportunity.hours = hours;
    opportunity.postingDate = postingDate;
    opportunity.locationName = locationName;

    opportunities.push(opportunity)

    console.log(opportunities); 

    browser.close();
}

(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const opportunities = [];

    let url = "https://recruiting2.ultipro.com/PUB1004PSCU/JobBoard/d433f5c3-37c8-4bcf-a3af-248a707c7d31/?q=&o=postedDateDesc"
    await page.goto(url, {timeout: 0, waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

    const oportunitiesDOM = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return document.getElementsByClassName('opportunity');
    });

    oportunitiesDOM.forEach(opo => {
        await crawlOpo(opo)
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
})()
```

The logic here is that it runs an `async` arrow function that will launch a browser -> load the page -> evalaute the page -> grab all the elements with the class `.opporuntity` -> loop over list and pass each opportunity into the `crawlOpo` function and then grab the specific data needed for that opportunity and then assign that object to an array.

Comment: Remove the `.` in the selection `document.getElementsByClassName('opportunity')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the argument of `document.getElementsByClassName('.opportunity')`, you have the CSS selector `'.opportunity'`.

The [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) method takes a name of a class as an argument, not a CSS selector.

Most likely it should be corrected to `document.getElementsByClassName('opportunity')`.

Comment: Yes that now gets the data but the data is not what was expected:

`{ '0': { __ko__1568043156424: 'ko169' },
  '1': { __ko__1568043156424: 'ko187' },
  '2': { __ko__1568043156424: 'ko205' },
  '3': { __ko__1568043156424: 'ko223' },
  }`